# how to update data in webform using Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I want to give my user a data table in which he/she can edit data.
I used this method to get my data from sql server

```
        public static List<TestAsfa> GetRecordsMan() {
        using (var d = new TestEntities())
        {
            return d.TestAsfa.ToList();
        }
```

I got stuck when I wanted to write the Delete Function

```
 protected void RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dt.Rows[GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].RowIndex].Delete();
            int id =Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ID);

            FillGridView();
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("<script> alert('Record not deleted...') </script>");
        }
    }
```

this is the delete function. I wrote the method below

```
public static void deleteRecord(int id)
    {

        using (var d = new TestEntities())
        {
            TestAsfa tb = d.TestAsfa.SingleOrDefault(t => t.ID == id);
            d.TestAsfa.Remove(tb);
            d.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

but I don't know it doesn't get the correct row id from sender
I don't understand my mistake

Answer (score 0):

For removing selected row use this code

```
 using(var d = new TestEntities())
 {
     d.TestAsfa.Remove(d.TestAsfa.Find(id));
     d.SaveChanges();
 }
```

or use this one

```
 using(var d = new TestEntities())
  {
     TestAsfa tb = d.TestAsfa.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
      d.TestAsfa.Remove(tb);
      d.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Comment: thanks  but I get this error   ex = {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity"}

Comment: this seem your Id have null value ,

Comment: the problem is rowID it always gets 0

Comment: you means there is the issue int id =Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ID);

Comment: yes I think I should use another way to get the Row ID

Comment: yea simple place label control in gridview with bind ID and get in this way int ID = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ID").toString());

Comment: sorry but now I get this    ex = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to prevent error you'll need to ensure that the id you're checking on is of an actual Item. Something like this, for example:

```
    public static void deleteRecord(TestAsfa TA,int id)
    { 
         using(var d = new TestEntities())
         {
            TA= d.TestAsfa.Where(item => item.ItemId == id).FirstOrDefault(); 
            if (itemTA!= null) {
               d.TestAsfa.Remove(TA);
            }
         }             

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try have a look at this

protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

```
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];  
        Label lbldeleteid = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");   
        conn.Open();  

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete FROM tableName where   
        id='"+Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString())+"'", conn);     

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       

        conn.Close();     
        gvbind();

    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is conn??

Comment: Data base connection string  .. we have to open the connection to execute the query !

Comment: you mean I should add this   string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestEntities"].ConnectionString;

Comment: yes.. if may be "TestEntities" your connection string name